# MVC 4 Ajax.BeginForm POST does not bind to model in conroller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

Sorry for the amount of code here but it's the best way to explain what;s happening.

I gave this code in my MVC 4 partial view:

```
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("TestPost", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }))
    {                               
        foreach (var d in Model.DataItemsWithLabels)
        {                                    
            @Html.LabelFor(m => d.DataName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => d.DataValue);             
        }

        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    }
```

And my controller action is as follows:

```
 public ActionResult TestPost(CmaPartialModel model)
 {         
        return PartialView("Transaction", model);
 }
```

In my model I have some code that populates a list of objects (only if they are empty) that are defined as:

```
 public List<DataItemWithLabel> DataItemsWithLabels { get; set; }      

    public class DataItemWithLabel
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        public string DataName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string DataValue { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have what  think is the correct web.config entries:

I have read a load of posts here and elsewhere with no success.

The code does post to the `TestPost` method but the model is always empty.  Can someone please tell me why this might be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you always get `null` value is the model binder doesn't know how to bind the list of Objects. See below example:

```
public class CmaPartialModel 
{
    public List<DataItemWithLabel> DataItemsWithLabels { get; set; } 
}
```

Then use it in you view:

```
@model  CmaPartialModel 

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("TestPost", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{
    for(var i = 0; i < Model.DataItemsWithLabels.Count; i++)
     {
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DataItemsWithLabels[i].DataName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DataItemsWithLabels[i].DataValue)
     }
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Finally, your action method should be like below:

```
 public ActionResult TestPost(CmaPartialModel model)
 {         
        return PartialView("Transaction", model);
 }
```

Update

You also can use `foreach` in your view like below:

```
foreach (var item in Model.DataItemsWithLabels.Select((value, i) => new { i, value }))
{
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DataItemsWithLabels[@item.i].DataName)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DataItemsWithLabels[@item.i].DataValue);   
}
```

Comment: thanks Lin - I already have a list exactly like that in my ViewModel - I jsu t called it CmaPartialModel.  Your solution is almost working but the only difference I can see is the for loop instead of the foreach - why is the foreach a problem or have I missed something?

Comment: hi @davy, the problem is not about using for or foreach to loop though all DataItemWithLabel models, you can use either one. The problem is when you use foreach to loop though all the items, model binder doesn't know how to bind data to it. So you need to create something like index to mark all items, then model binder binds the data for all list of items. I updated my answer about how to use foreach to do this, take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

```
I think below code will help you.
```

**View**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.CmaPartialModel   
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("TestPost", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }))
 {
   if (Model != null)
    {
    foreach (var d in Model.DataItemsWithLabels)
    {                                    
        @Html.LabelFor(m => d.DataName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => d.DataValue);
    }
   }
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

**Model**

```
public class CmaPartialModel
{
    public List<DataItemWithLabel> DataItemsWithLabels { get; set; }

    public class DataItemWithLabel
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        public string DataName { get; set; }

        public string DataValue { get; set; }
    }  
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult TestPost(CmaPartialModel model)
    {
        List<CmaPartialModel.DataItemWithLabel> parts = new      List<CmaPartialModel.DataItemWithLabel>();
        parts.Add(new CmaPartialModel.DataItemWithLabel() {DisplayName = "abc",DataName = "cbv",DataValue = "343"});
        parts.Add(new CmaPartialModel.DataItemWithLabel() { DisplayName = "sfda", DataName = "xzfdsf", DataValue = "234" });
        model.DataItemsWithLabels = parts;
        return PartialView("Index", model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your Post method as follows

```
public ActionResult TestPost(IEnumerable<DataItemWithLabel> model)
 {         
        return PartialView("Transaction", model);
 }
```

Since you're passing a collection of your `DataItemWithLabel` models to your controller.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense - although my DataItemWithLabel is within the model CmaPartialModel so that returns null.