# Multiple ajax request from a razor view having IEnumerable model/viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, ajax.beginform

In my ASP.Net MVC project I have following ViewModel

```
public class ApproveItemViewModel
{
        [Required]
        public int ItemId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }
}
```

I have following two methods in controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ListPendingItems()
    {
        var items = new List<ApproveItemViewModel>();
        //add few items here in above list
        return View(vms);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ApproveItem(ApproveItemViewModel viewmodel)
    {
        return Json(new { success = success }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Now in my razor view what I want is to call ApporveItem method using Ajax calls for each individual item. so I created multiple ajax form using below code.

```
@model IEnumerable<ApproveItemViewModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    using (Ajax.BeginForm("ApproveItem", new AjaxOptions()
                        {
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            HttpMethod = "POST",
                            UpdateTargetId = "dane"
                        }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => item.ItemId)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ItemId)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => item.ItemCode)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.ItemCode))</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Approve" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
}
```

However in the controller action method parameter I get both ItemId and ItemCode as 0 and null respectively. Whats the problem here, could anyone help please? How can we pass the viewmodel to action using ajax?

Comment: You have included the **@Html.AntiforgeryToken** , so make sure that your request contains the **_requestVarificationToken** as well.

Comment: You view makes no sense. You can only post back one form at a time so why are you generating a form for each item in your collection. The model in your view is `List<ApproveItemViewModel>` so therefore the POST method needs to be `public JsonResult ApproveItem(List<ApproveItemViewModel> viewmodel)` and you generate the form controls in a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate` inside one form (an post back all changes at once)

Comment: Alternatively, generate the table as text only, and use a modal form to edit a selected item and post back to `public JsonResult ApproveItem(ApproveItemViewModel viewmodel)` Although your method suggests all you want to do is 'Approve' an item so why can the user edit the `ItemId` and `ItemCode` properties?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Initially only itemId will be there, as part of approval we need to update ItemCode.

Comment: OK, So then either generate all the controls inside one form if your expecting the user to edit most or all items and post back all at once, or include a dialog form that is opened when you click on an item and use ajax to submit it.

Comment: And `@Html.LabelFor(m => item.ItemId)` makes no sense (you don't have an editable for control for `ItemId` - in fact you don't have a control for that at all so you would at least need a hidden input)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that the Model Binder in the view doesn't know how to bind your list of ApproveItemViewModel's.

See this answer for an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21191624/2521893

```
@model IEnumerable<ApproveItemViewModel>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    using (Ajax.BeginForm("ApproveItem", new AjaxOptions()
                        {
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            HttpMethod = "POST",
                            UpdateTargetId = "dane"
                        }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => Model[i].ItemId)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].ItemId)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => Model[i].ItemCode)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].ItemCode))</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Approve" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. The POST method parameter would need to be `List<ApproveItemViewModel>` and then only the first form will ever bind (the `DefaultModelBinder` required that collection indexers start at zero and be consecutive)

Answer (score 0):

Cause of this issue is 'parameter' name. You need to keep same name for both controller post action's parameter(ie, viewmodel)  and iterating model(item) in cshtml side, then only binding should happened. See the two different solutions below.

**Solution 1** : Modify cshtml page:-
Replace @foreach (var item in Model) with @foreach (var viewmodel in Model)
ie,

```
@foreach (var viewmodel in Model)
```

**Solution 2** : Modify  controller action:-Change ApproveItem action's parameter name.
ie,

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ApproveItem(ApproveItemViewModel item)
{
    return Json(new { success = success }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```